# 2 wordpress, 2 different themes, some pages with the same content

Tags: multisite

Let's say I have 2 wordpress sites, wordpress1.com and wordpress2.com. Both websites have different theme. Some contents are the same (which means updating a page / post will reflect on both sites) but some are different. I have done some research I'm not sure if multisite or syndicate out plugin can meet all of my requirements.

Please advise

Comment: MultiSites don't share content by default. You are probably looking more for a syndication solution.

Comment: Also, be careful of SEO penalization because of duplicate content, you should at least include a `link` tag in the `head` of the syndicated pages with name `canonical_url` and `href` to the original url. A plugin of SEO could help you to generate the right tags, but your syndication solution should care about this too.